# how can I change the thickness of the pen on the canvas below using an input range?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change the thickness of the pen on canvas with JQuery?
I have used a canvas and I want to put the range below the canvas and it should be hidden when the page is loaded and after clicking on a button it should be appeared.

```css
body {
 background: #384047;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}
canvas {
 background: #fff;
 display: block;
 margin: 50px auto 10px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 0 0 #222;
cursor: url(http://s8.picofile.com/file/8333405442/download.png), pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="001.css">
    </head>
    <body>
            <canvas width="600" height="400" ></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the pen?

Comment: http://s8.picofile.com/file/8333405442/download.png here it is

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example, I'll quickly explain:

You cannot change the width and height of the `cursor` property in CSS, only the x and y coordinates - read the [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor). So to render a custom cursor, simply make a new `Image` object, set `cursor: none;` and render the custom cursor on the canvas like you would any other canvas element. The slider value scales the width and height of the cursor. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c"); //define DOM content
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var slider = document.getElementById("range");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

var clicked = false;

var cursor = new Image(); //load img
cursor.src = "cursor.png"; //change this to your img
cursor.w = cursor.h = 50;

btn.addEventListener("click", e => { //When btn is clicked
  slider.style.display = "block"; //display range
});

c.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(cursor, e.pageX - cursor.w/2, e.pageY - cursor.h/2, cursor.w, cursor.h);
});

slider.addEventListener("click", e => {
  check();
});

function check() {
  if (slider.value !== cursor.w) { //if unique value
    cursor.w = cursor.h = slider.value; //width and height scale based on slider
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  cursor: none;
}

#range {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="400" ></canvas>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="activate" />
<input id="range" type="range" />
```